# Primefaces ajax charset

Tags: mysql, ajax, primefaces, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem updating values with a p:commandbutton.when in p:commandButton , I am set ajax="true" all thing is Ok , but when I am set ajax="false" , value in the p:inputText do not encoding and in the next page show me ÙØ±ÛÙ . or when send to mysql database .
I am using Filter but my problem does not solve.

please Help me
Thanks

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:inputText value="#{bean.name}" />
            <p:commandButton value="check" ajax="false" action="page2"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put the meta-tag inside the h:head. Also you can do it in either a template or with a PhaseListener, if you'd like to avoid doing it in all pages.

Comment: Hi , Thanks , But please give me details of meta-tag or template with a PhaseListener

Answer (score 2):

I should use Filter for solve this problem.

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>myengineer.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and java class filter

```
package myengineer;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author alfa
 */
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter{
                   ///===================================================================================
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    //No-op
}
    ///===================================================================================
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain       chain) 
                                                       throws IOException,     ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    ///==================================================================================
    public void destroy() {
        //No-op
    }    
    ///===================================================================================
}
```